# Is it possible to rename fields in django restframework

Tags: django-rest-framework

My python code has fields named like `field_name` which is fine for python and works well with Django.

Lots of Javascript linters want you to make it fieldName or they whine at you a lot.

Trying to find a nice common ground between the two, I've written serializers like

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fieldName = serializers.WritableField(source='field_name', required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Widget
        exclude = ('field_name',)
```

Problem is that this does NOT replace the external representation of field_name with fieldName, it sends both fieldName and field_name.  So I told it to exclude the ('field_name').  Then when you are trying to save, it gets really upset because field_name isn't present, or fieldName isn't a member of the object.

I had thought that mapping would be a good way to do this, but it doesn't appear to be so.  Is there someway to map the names from python -> javascript so the code can look pretty on both ends?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a package that takes care of it at the json level:

https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-camel-case/

Documentation is very sparse, but it appears to work, and integrating it is trivial (which might explain the sparse documentation).

Answer (score 2):

You code **should** be working. So there's something missing from the example

The thing that comes to mind is your `fields` value — what do you have specified there? It's generally better to explicitly specify the fields you want there rather than using `exclude` — it takes longer to set up (maybe) but it'll save time in the long run.

If `fieldName` is included in `fields` and `field_name` is not I would expect your code to work.

(Perhaps show a little more if that doesn't solve it.)

**Update after edit to question**

Ok. Yes. You should specify the fields you want. Your `fieldName` is acting as an extra field with its source as `field_name` — this sort of thing is useful when using SerializerMethodField for example.

**Update: Extra Solution**

There's a [ticket asking about Camel-casing field names for better compatibility with e.g. JavaScript clients](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/944). This links to a [Gist with a working solution via custom renderer and parser classes](https://gist.github.com/vbabiy/5842073).

Comment: I updated the code to what I'm using.  I'm getting both fieldName and field_name in the output unless I have the exclude line.  Good to know I'm not off base when it comes to that.  To bad we don't have a plunker for python....